# Apache Velocity standard logging configuration creates far too much log output

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, logging, velocity

I have a small web Page Project I have templated with velocity

My web.xml configuration is pretty simple

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
</init-param>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Log is full with this kind of logging from org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext

```
Nov 06, 2014 4:25:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION:  Velocity   [info] WebappResourceLoader: added template path - '/WEB-INF/velocity/'
Nov 06, 2014 4:25:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION:  Velocity  [trace] WebappResourceLoader: initialization complete.
Nov 06, 2014 4:25:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION:  Velocity  [debug] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader
```

The Log entrances always look like:
'date' PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION:  Velocity 'some pretty useless information'.

I have standard tomcat Configuration and would like to avoid changing something on tomcat level. Still don't know what to do with pretty useless 60 MB Log files per day.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of logs? I know the velocity documentation on logging [velocity logging](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Logging) and I find it a little bit confusing.

Any help will be appreciated…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Claude Brisson Answer is probably correct if you are using log4j in your application. The Last part helped me the most.

I am using commons-logging-1.1.jar as in the examples of the velocity project. So adding just this 2 lines of configuration to `/WEB-INF/velocity.properties` was the solution:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute
runtime.log.logsystem.servlet.level = info
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra line **is** from tomcat, so you would see it with any webapp, and you won't be able to remove it without touching tomcat configuration. It's not straightforward, but it's not that hard. See for instance **[how to set up log4j logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_log4j)** (this page is for tomcat 7, but please adapt if it's not your tomcat version). In a nutshell:

1. download log4j 1.2+ jar from **[log4j download page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html)** and put it in `tomcat/lib`
2. download `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar` and log4j's `tomcat-juli.jar` from the extras section of **[tomcat 7 download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)**. `tomcat-juli.jar` goes in `tomcat/bin` and `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar` goes in `tomcat/lib`.
3. you must now set up a `tomcat/lib/log4j.properties` file. There are several examples around, here's one that logs all webapps in a daily-rotated `tomcat/logs/tomcat.log` file:

   log4j.rootCategory=info, rotating
   log4j.appender.rotating=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.rotating.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log 
   log4j.appender.rotating.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
   log4j.appender.rotating.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.rotating.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n

Once you got rid of this extra line, then you can set up Velocity log level. Here's the relevant portion of `/WEB-INF/velocity.properties`:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute
runtime.log.logsystem.servlet.level = info
```

Comment: For the moment tomcat can't find log4j.properties in the lib directory but i am still working on it...

Comment: Be sure to regularly check catalina.out for errors.